# htaccess rewrite rule - question mark to "&" sign

Tags: .htaccess

I need help to write an htaccess rewrite rule that will read a question mark sign in query string into "&" .

Ex.

```
  http://site.com/aa/?arg=1 
  http://site.com/aa/bb/?arg=1
```

into

```
 http://site.com/aa/&arg=1
 http://site.com/aa/bb/&arg=1
```

The reason why I want to do this  is specific to the MVC I made myself. Thanks

Comment: Might be bad, `GET` uses ampersands to concatenate values.

Comment: I actually have an existing htaccess rule that rewrites  urls like http://site.com/aa/  into http://site.com?aa/ . I am just seeking for clues how to adapt my MVC when using a GET method in form submission, since such method would append ? rather than & , causing my MVC to break  ( ex http://site.com?aa?argss=1  rather than  http://site.com?aa&argss=1 with GET method in form).

Answer (score 0):

So you have an existing htaccess rule that rewrites urls like site.com/aa into site.com?aa.
You only have to append that rule with `&%{QUERY_STRING}` which will add your new params to the end of the parameter list.